# Best tool for managing IIS metabase

Tags: iis

What is the best tool for managing IIS metabase?

A free tool please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Metabase Explorer version 1.6**

Microsoft's Metabase Explorer 1.6 (MBExplorer.exe), part of the [IIS 6.0 Resource Kit](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B840671&x=&y=)), provides a graphical user interface (GUI) for viewing and for editing local and remote IIS metabase stores. You can also use Metabase Explorer to do the following:

- Edit security settings for keys
- Export and import keys and subkeys
- Copy and paste keys and subkeys
- Compare records

And: yes, it's free. You can [download the IIS 6.0 resource kit here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1352).